# How to stop dev tools (inspect element) on Chrome from closing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, web-inspector, google-developer-tools

After a while, even if the window is active, the developer tools (inspect element) tab will auto-close, this is bad since I have to always keep it open to emulate a touch device, I've looked through the settings and can't see anything about disabling this functionality.

Comment: Normally it never happens, so it must be a bug.